# how can i get "click" message after hovering over a button through CSS

Tags: html, css, button

when I hover on  a button, I'm not able to get that message like click or enter or start etc.
how can I style my button through css to get that message before actually clicking a button ?

I used things like .button-subscribe:after etc but I am not sure what CSS will actualy work

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: Also please install a spell checker.

Comment: `button` elements have text allowable inside them which would be your message. What else do you need? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: @Paulie_D I've checked, but my point is about the tooltip

Comment: Again, why do you need a tooltip since your message is already in the button?

Comment: I just want to know how things work  in CSS. I am new to WEB

Comment: You could use the HTML Attribute "title" like this: title="Click me!" This is called tooltip and does bot need CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pseudo-element `:after` as you indicated. Just position it how you want.

```css
.styled {
  border: 0;
  line-height: 2.5;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(220, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: relative;
}

.styled:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.styled::after {
  content: "Tooltip";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50%;
  color: grey;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: none;
}

.styled:hover::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="favorite styled" type="button">Add to favorites</button>
```